# does this magic system permit perpetual motion?

Tags: magic

I've designed a magic system and I'm wondering if it follows the property of entropy. it has eight different types of magic: lux, pyr, hydr, aero, necrom, terra, prestia, and bizarre.

The first six are known as the hexachromal magics, each being associated with color and the magics are attracted to those with the most similar colors and repelled by those that are the most different. Pyr is orange, hydr is blue, terra is green, lux is yellow, aero is red, and necrom is purple. There are also certain metals that interact with these magics, known as magimetals. Each one is associated with a particular magic and is attract strongly to it and repelled by the complementary color, with no interaction with those in between. gold has the property of being attractive to magic up to a point and then repulsive, making magic float above it in currents that move in a similar way to electricity. other conductors can have similar effects, but to a much lesser degree, and with a much more unstable equilibrium.

Prestia and bizarre are a pair, strongly attracted to one another, but their magimetals are strongly repelled to the opposite magic and attracted to the opposite metal. The magics, in turn, are strongly repelled by each other's metals.

Magimetals all weigh 45 kilograms per cubic meter at 0 degrees Celsius, and all the hexochromic magics are 0.04 kilograms per cubic meter under the same circumstances, with prestia and bizarre being 0.07.

Spells work by making the magic vibrate at a certain frequency, which directly correlates to its temperature, and use crystalline minerals that focus corresponding magics into a certain range of frequencies or temperatures. When magics that dont correspond to a focus are sent through, their frequencies are forced further away. The lower the frequency the magic moves at, the more 'sluggish' it becomes while inactive, so if you were to decrease the frequency of magic enough, it would act almost like a liquid, and be very cold due to frequency corresponding to heat. In a way, the higher the frequency, the more magic acts like a wave in a vacuum.

Comment: bit of a wall of text

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your query into well formed sentences & paragraphs.

Comment: Would capacity for perpetual motion / generally following the laws of entropy be a good thing, or a bad thing?  Do spells cost the users anything energetically?  Will magimetals be subject with all existing physical laws (friction, gravity, etc), and will magic be subject to these laws?

Comment: I'm hoping that it doesn't permit perpetual motion. casting spells does require energy that directly relates to the amount of energy it takes to raise the temperature of magic, and yes, magimetals act physically similarly to normal metals in all ways except in relation to magic (they act most similarly to pure iron) and magic acts most similarly to either electrons, light, or helium depending on frequency, but are always repelled by magnetism.

Comment: It "raises the temperature of magic", but magic acts like "electrons, light, or helium depending on the frequency"?  Light doesn't have a temperature, and temperature affects electrons by reducing the effective resistance in a medium.  If you have more information fleshed out on how magic / magimetals work, please edit your original question with that info.  The more detailed and better-defined your question, the better folks will be able to answer it within the bounds of your system

Comment: So, magic is actually a type of matter? It has density, temperature, and can vibrate. I don't think I've seen any magic system where "magic" itself is a physical object, it's typically more like an energy or power to do something. If someone told me they had a "box of magic", I would be pretty surprised if it was a box filled with a physical material that they called "magic". Do you mine it out of the ground, or excrete it, or what?

Comment: im using temperature and frequency interchangeably here because magic acts as both a particle and a wave simultaneously and how closely it corresponds with one of the two depends on how much energy it has. the electron comparison is due to how it interacts with gold, flowing in a current thats constantly moving along the medium, the light comparison is due to its behavior with frequency, and the helium one is from its nature of being virtually incapable of forming bonds and moving like a gaseous particle.

Comment: @nuclear hoagie it is technically a particle, though it doesnt always act like one. their movement coils instead of straightening out when they gain momentum, and it can (under the right circumstances) even move through massive objects. and yes, the idea of magic acting like a quantum particle is my own thing, since i couldnt think of a way to neatly fit magic in as a type of energy to fit with particle physics.

Comment: the description of how your magic works may be too abstract to get a feeling for this, why not add an example or two of usage. also it would help if we knew how much energy it takes to do things, for instance where does the energy for two things to repel each other come from? Is the repulsion static or changable? ect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Spells work by making the magic vibrate at a certain frequency, which
> directly correlates to its temperature, and use crystalline minerals
> that focus corresponding magics into a certain range of frequencies or
> temperatures.

A 'perpetual motion machine' is just another way of saying that entropy is ignored. That is, in a closed system where entropy exists (meaning through every exchange of energy, the degree of entropy in the entire closed system increases) then a perpetual motion machine is impossible. Let's write it down as a rule stated like this:

**"If the degree of entropy increases in a closed system, no perpetual motion machine can exist."**

Conversely, the opposite is true. If entropy does *not* hold true and you can arbitrarily decrease the amount of entropy in a system, or keep it the same despite the fact that energy is being changed within the closed system, then not only can a perpetual motion machine be possible, it *has* to be possible. That rule can be stated as such:

**"If entropy does not automatically increase in a closed system, a perpetual motion machine must be able to exist."**

Now, fundamentally, entropy and energy are linked. If you can increase the amount of energy in a system, that is, defy the First Law of Thermodynamics and *create* energy, then you can also decrease the amount of entropy using that created energy. This third rule can be written down as follows:

**"If energy can be created, entropy can be decreased."**

And, conversely, for our fourth rule, the opposite is true:

**"If energy cannot be created, entropy cannot be decreased."**

As our world follows First Law of thermodynamics (we can't create energy), and the universe tends towards entropy, our universe is one where a perpetual motion machine is impossible. Now that we have the background finished, let's answer your question.

It depends on the magic system. The way your magic system works seems to be by having magic vibrate at a specific frequency. If the energy used to make the magic vibrate at the frequency is *greater* than what the magic gives off (like a glass of water in a microwave), then a perpetual motion machine is impossible. Alternatively, if the energy used to make the magic vibrate is *less* or *equal* to what the magic gives off, then a perpetual motion machine must be possible. I hope this helps.